# Why is my model null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Being new to c# I can't figure out the issue I am having. I have created a view and still, my model is null, what could be causing this?

**Below is my Model:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Prigmore2013_01.Models
{
    public class GuessingGame
    {
        private Random _random;

        public GuessingGame()
        {
            this._random = new Random();
            this.Guesses = new List<Guess>();
            this.Target = new List<int>(){ 1, 2, 3 };
        }

        public List<int> Target { get; set; }
        public List<Guess> Guesses { get; set; }

        public List<Guess> ShowGuessesMade()
        {
            return Guesses;
        }
        public void NewGame()
        {
            this.Target.Clear();
            var count = 4;
            for (var i = 1; i < count; i++)
            {
                var swap = _random.Next(1, 9);

                if (!this.Target.Contains(swap))
                {
                    this.Target.Add(swap);
                }
            }
        }
        public void GuessTheHiddenDigits(List<int> guesses)
        {
            Guess g = new Guess() { Digits = guesses };
            //compare the lists
            var list = this.Target;
            var list2 = g.Digits;

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                if (list[i] == list2[i])
                {
                    g.RightDigitRightPosition++;
                }
            }
            //Now calculate how many digits in guesses are just plain wrong
            List<int> result = g.Digits.Except(this.Target).ToList();
            g.RightDigitWrongPosition = g.Digits.Count - result.Count - g.RightDigitRightPosition;

            //handle duplicates
            if (list.Count != list2.Distinct().Count())
            {
                // set thet right digit wrong position
                for (int i = 0; i < list2.Distinct().Count(); i++)
                {
                    g.RightDigitWrongPosition = i;
                }
            }
            this.Guesses.Add(g);
        }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    @model Prigmore2013_01.Models.GuessingGame
}
<h2>Guessing The Digits</h2>
<p>Insert your 3 guesses into the textboxes below</p>
<form action="Exercise09/GuessTheDigits" method="post">
    <label for="guesses">Guess 1: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Guesses[0], new { style = "width:12px", MaxLength = "1" }) Guess 2: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Guesses[1], new { style = "width:12px", MaxLength = "1" }) Guess 3: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Guesses[2], new { style = "width:12px", MaxLength = "1" })</label>
    <br />

    <label for="pastGuesses">Your Previous Guesses</label>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Your Guess</td>
            <td>Spot On</td>
            <td>Near Miss</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Need to loop here -->
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < Model.Guesses.Count(); i++)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.Guesses)
                { 
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Digits)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.RightDigitRightPosition)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.RightDigitWrongPosition)</td>
            </tr>
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <p>Fail - Model is null</p>
        }
    </table>

    <button type="submit" name="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<form action="Exercise09/StartNewGame" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="Submit">New Game</button>
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
using Prigmore2013_01.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Prigmore2013_01.Tests
{
    public class Exercise09Controller : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Exercise09/

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }



        public ViewResult ShowPreviousGuesses()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Session["GameState"] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Session["GameState"] = new GuessingGame();
            }

            GuessingGame theGame = this.Session["GameState"] as GuessingGame;
            return View("Index", theGame.Guesses);
        }




        public ViewResult ShowGuessesMade()
        {
            return View();
        }



        public ActionResult GuessTheDigits(List<int> guesses)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Session["GameState"] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Session["GameState"] = new GuessingGame();
            }

            GuessingGame theGame = this.Session["GameState"] as GuessingGame;

            theGame.GuessTheHiddenDigits(guesses);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", theGame.Guesses);
        }




        public RedirectToRouteResult StartNewGame()
        {
            GuessingGame theGame = this.Session["GameState"] as GuessingGame;
            theGame.Target.Clear();
            var rand = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (!theGame.Target.Contains(rand.Next(1, 10)))
                {
                    theGame.Target.Add(rand.Next(1, 10));
                }
            }


            return RedirectToRoute(new
            {
                controller = "Exercise09",
                action = "Index"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I think I am along the right lines but can't understand what is causing this problem? Would someone be able to link me to appropriate reading material for a further understanding so that I can prevent this in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view is expecting:

```
@model Prigmore2013_01.Models.GuessingGame
```

But you are passing:

```
return View("Index", theGame.Guesses);
```

Either change your view to expect a `List<Prigmore2013_01.Models.Guess>`:

```
@model List<Prigmore2013_01.Models.Guess>
```

Or change your controller to send a `Prigmore2013_01.Models.GuessingGame` to the view:

```
return View("Index", theGame);
```

Based on your code it would seem more intuitive to change the return types of your controller methods to return the GuessingGame object.

Answer (score 1):

Your model is `GuessingGame` and you are passing a `List<Guess>`. In your view change it to:

```
@model List<Prigmore2013_01.Models.Guess>
```

Also, on your `Index` action method you are not passing anything as a model to the view so that would also cause it to be `null`.

Bottom line, you either have to change your view to accept the proper type or change your controller action methods to pass the proper type.